# Have Model Save as Modified Value

Tags: json, angularjs

This is a piece of code I'm working with right now:

```
<select ng-model="rule.platforms" ng-options="platform for platform in platforms" 
        name="platform" multiple required>
  <option value="">-- platform --</option>
</select>
```

The default behavior of a multiple select in Angular is to bind an array to the model. For example:

```
rule.platforms = ["twitter", "google"]
```

However, because of how this needs to be saved into the database all the values need to be joined together into one string. Right now the clearest solution seems to be to parse the value right before saving/updating, but doing so will add a lot of logic as it will be necessary to go through all the data and check for each rule.

What I would really like to do is have a means of changing how the value being binded to the model is stored initially, so instead of the above it would save with this kind of value:

```
rule.platforms = "twitter, google"
```

Is this even possible? I've been going over Angular documentation but haven't come across anything like this. If anyone knows an easy means of achieving this behavior please let me know!

** **EDIT** **

For the sake of clarifying my specific use case I wanted to include the data structure in question:

```
$scope.data = 
{
  project: {
    name: "",
    topics_attributes: [
      {
        name: "",
        feed_size: "",
        topic_sources_attributes: [
          {
            platform: "",
            keywords: "",
            authors: ""
          }
        ],
        rules_attributes: [
          {
            name: "",
            platforms: "",
            conditional: "",
            terms: ""
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The issue is with rules_attributes.platforms as rules_attributes and all of its children are created dynamically. If this was a static model parameter then the solution Mike suggested would work perfectly. Unfortunately, the dynamic nature of the model makes it difficult to change as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the easiest way to achieve this would be to use a temporary scope variable to hold the platforms. You can then watch the temporary variable for change with $watch, parse the value and update your rule.platforms with the string value.

Edit: I imagined you'd have something similar to this very simplified approach:
http://jsfiddle.net/oqwh5gs7/12/

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.rule = {};
  $scope.rule.platforms = ['google'];
  $scope.tempPlatforms = [];
  $scope.platforms = ['google', 'twitter'];

  for(var i in $scope.rule.platforms) {
    $scope.tempPlatforms[i] = $scope.rule.platforms[i];
  }

  $scope.$watch('tempPlatforms', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.rule.platforms = newValue.join();
  });
}
```

If the available platforms are fixed there shouldn't be a problem about updating the correct rule. You could put the select inside a directive and pass the current rule via the "=" or "&" binding depending on your needs. If the available platforms change according the current rule this could get a bit trickier, of course...

**EDIT:** I am still not sure whether I understand the problem correctly, but I updated my fiddle with a way to dynamically create new rules to demonstrate how I imagine your problem to be: http://jsfiddle.net/oqwh5gs7/16/

Essentially I only created a directive for the select and added a $scope.$watch('rule',...) to reflect dynamic changes of the rule.

Comment: Doing that how would it be possible to update the correct rule.platforms? In this use case "rule" is nested under "topic" and a "rule" is dynamically generated such that there can be multiple instances of "rule" at any given time.